# What is the most unified functional model of the hippocampus?

Tags: reference-request, theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling

There are many different incremental models of the hippocampus and it's role in learning as shown by a quick search. However, have there been any efforts to combine these various models into a single unified functional model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself have not come across a complete end-to-end hippocampal model, but I would imagine that such an implementation would be quite broad in scope. Edmund Rolls has some nice papers on the hippocampus, one of which is a particularly informative and recent review:

Kesner RP, and Rolls ET. A computational theory of hippocampal function, and tests of the theory: New developments. *Neuroscience and Biobehavioral Reviews* 48 (2015) 92-147 [PDF here (Second page missing?)](http://www.oxcns.org/papers/539%20Kesner%20Rolls%202014%20A%20theory%20of%20hippocampal%20function.pdf)

I'll be very interested to read other answers to your question.